# setting/assigning value confusion in script

Tags: javascript

Please check first below

```
$('#ResetButton').click(function() {
    alert($('#test').html());  // ALERT WORKING FINE
    $('#test').editable('setValue',null); // THIS DOESN'T RUN
});
```

I'm confused why alert is working but the next line doesn't. I tried testing in fiddle and it worked fine, but it doesn't on my app. my app contains bootstrap and x-editable. could you give any speculation?

Here's another, lines have been interchanged.

```
$('#ResetButton').click(function() {
    $('#test').editable('setValue',null); // THIS DOESN'T RUN
    alert($('#test').html());  // AND SO AS THIS LINE, DOESN'T WORK
});
```

and lastly...

```
$('#test').editable('setValue','Hello World'); // THIS WORKS
$('#ResetButton').click(function() {
    $('#test').editable('setValue',null); // THIS DOESN'T RUN
    alert($('#test').html());  // AND SO AS THIS LINE, DOESN'T WORK

});
```

Comment: any errors from the console?

Comment: What is `editable` a plugin ? which one ?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'editable'

Comment: If you say it works in fiddle but not your app I suspect some of the file didn't load properly (or out of order) check your dev tools console for 404 errors, are you loading jQuery before editable plugin?

Comment: @sheik - x-editable i guess

Comment: @eru - ok tnx for hte info, i'm seeing 404's in my console, i will investigate.. no Jquery..

Comment: @eru - 404's gone.. but same problem...

Comment: here's my tag..<a href="#" id="test" class="myeditable"></a>

Comment: only error left in console is Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'editable'

Comment: good, and "editable" plugin is loaded after jquery?

Comment: yes sir it's loaded...

Comment: If it was loaded, you wouldn't get that error. Or you are using the plugin incorrectly.

Comment: @felix - the 3rd supplied codes about shows that editable works outside the resetbutton, doesn't work if inside the resetbutton, both resides inside a script, doesn't that mean editable was loaded? im new to this so if i am missing something, kindly correct me. tia.

Comment: problem partly solved... i just excluded "require.js" and worked fine.. yup conflict issue... problem now is that.. i need require.js. what must i do?

Comment: my app requires require.js for FUELUX plugin... i guess i just have to dump it... back to work now.. tnx everyone!